# How can I know if the namespace of a package is imported by others?

Tags: r, namespaces, detach

This triggers a warning :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
detach("package:glue", unload = TRUE)
# Warning message:
#   l'espace de noms ‘glue’ ne peut être déchargé :
#   l'espace de noms ‘glue’ est importé par ‘tidyr’, ‘dplyr’ et ne peut, donc, pas être déchargé
```

(excuse my French)

I would like to anticipate the warning, so I'm looking for a function similar to `is_unloadable` below :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
is_unloadable(glue) # 
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: `loadedNamespaces()` (forgot about this one … sigh)

Comment: this one is to safe in the other direction, `intersect(loadedNamespaces(), gsub("^package:","",search()))` show `tidyverse`, which unloads without a warning